# Seaborn/Matplotlib in Pool - fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1"

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am having difficulties with my program freezing when I try to create plots in a pool with Seaborn/Matplotlib. Running the code in a pool alone is fine, but if I run some other code before it which also makes figures, I get errors, and the program hangs (see error outputs below). This code is a very simplified example where I managed to replicate the error partly, but when I run it in my actual project my whole computer hangs, and I have to log in to a new session and killall python3 to unfreeze. The data sets I use and the program I have for it is quite complex so I hope this code sample will suffice. The error messages seem to have something to do with the X display server so I think it is the same issue.

If I run the function make_boxplot without calling the functions to the pool it runs fine, and vice versa, but if I run them together in the same script the errors shown below occur.

What could be causing this? Judging from the outputs it seems to hang at the call to plt.figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd


def make_figure(name):
    print("making figure " + name)
    fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
    print("created figure " + name)
    ax = fig1.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.figure.savefig("temp_out/" + name + ".png")
    plt.close(fig1)


def make_boxplot():
    fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
    ax = fig1.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

    index = ['frank', 'jen', 'cindy', 'jabba']
    a = pd.Series(data=[5, 10, 20, 22], index=index, name='a')
    b = pd.Series(data=[7, 9, 5, 6], index=index, name='b')
    c = pd.Series(data=[3, 2, 1, 4], index=index, name='c')
    df = pd.concat([a, b, c], axis=1)

    # sns.boxplot(data=df, palette="Set3", ax=ax)
    # for item in ax.get_xticklabels():
    #     item.set_rotation(90)
    fig1.savefig("temp_out/" + "my_boxplot.png")
    plt.close(fig1)


if not os.path.exists("temp_out"):
    os.makedirs("temp_out")

make_boxplot()

names = ['bob', 'billy', 'josef', 'jane', 'tarzan', 'phil', 'cindy']

pool = Pool(4)
pool.map_async(make_figure, names)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

**Output:**

```
making figure bob
making figure billy
making figure josef
making figure jane
XIO:  fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server ":1"
      after 432 requests (432 known processed) with 25 events remaining.
XIO:  fatal IO error 25 (Inappropriate ioctl for device) on X server ":1"
      after 428 requests (428 known processed) with 25 events remaining.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1"
      after 428 requests (428 known processed) with 23 events remaining.
making figure tarzan
making figure phil
making figure cindy
created figure cindy
created figure phil
created figure tarzan
```

Comment: Have you found any resolution to your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Although, I have had partial success. You might want to try setting the matplotlib backend to be 'Agg' to enable non-interactive plotting. This way, any conflicts arising due to DISPLAY unavailability (?) might be resolved.

Comment: @Sameeresque this did the trick. I just faced a similar issue (I got Success instead of Resource temporary unavailable). Link to the documentation https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend